# Unable to get hang of writing nested for loops

Tags: c++

I have to use nested for loops for the middle part of this figure:

```
    +------+  <-- line
    |  ^^  |  <-- This is the first line of body
    | ^  ^ |  <-- This is the 2nd line of body
    |^    ^|  <-- This is the 3rd line of body
    +------+ <--  line
```

for line, I wrote:

```
    void line()
    {
       int i, width = 6;
       cout << "+";
       for(i=0; i<width; i++)
       {
          cout << "-";
       }
       cout << "+" << endl;
    }
```

and it outputs correctly. But I can't figure a nested for loop to produce e the output between the 2 lines

Comment: Start with how you would draw this by hand.  Draw it. Take good notes on the steps you took. The notes become the basis for the code.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still not able to see a pattern to use in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: a for loop to output a 6x6 box looks like this:

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 6; j++){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

So the next step is to figure out out to make the characters vary at different spaces. Here is an example of adding conditionals to your for loops to change the characters of different spaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l = 3; 
    int r = 4;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 6; j++){
            if(j == l || j == r)
               cout << "^";
            else
               cout << "*";
        }
        l -= 1;
        r += 1;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That worked great, thank you! I modified it slightly to:

Comment: void top()
         {
             int l = 3; 
             int r = 4;

            for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
              cout << "|";
              for(int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
              {
                  if((j == l || j == r))
                     cout << "^";
                  else
                     cout << " ";
              }
           l -= 1;
           r += 1;
           cout << "|";
           cout << endl;
           }

        }

Comment: @Newbie No problem man, I'm glad I could help! I would appreciate it if you upvoted my answer too. Thanks!